# getActivity().getActionBar() is giving null on fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a fragment , where I need to change the title of ActionBar dynamically. But when I am using the following code, it is giving me `NullPointerException`. Here `getActionBar()` is returning null,my question is how can I get the reference of `ActionBar` in `Fragment` class. Appreciate your help in advance.

Fragment Class code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      ActionBar mActionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
      mActionBar.setTitle("Your new score is :"+ i);
      return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is make a call back from your fragment like below:

Create a call back

```
public interface OnActionBarListener {
        void onChangeActionBarTitle(int score);
    }
```

and implement it in your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnActionBarListener {
    @Override
    public void onChangeActionBarTitle(int score) {
       mActionBar.setTitle("Your new score is :"+ score);
    }
}
```

and in your fragment

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    OnActionBarListener mListener;

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof YourActivity) {
            mListener = (OnActionBarListener) context;
        }

    }
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       if (mListener != null) mListener.onChangeActionBarTitle(i);
       return rootView;
}

}
```

Hope this helps !

**UPDATE 1:** base on your request, if you want your activity listen every button click on your fragment, try below code in your fragment

```
Button mButton1;
Button mButton2;

mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                changeTitle(your_score);
            }
        });
mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                changeTitle(your_score);
            }
        });

void changeTitle(int score) {
        if (mListener != null) mListener.onChangeActionBarTitle(i);
    }
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do with my fragment but I need to change the title on button click, so I need the activity to listen on every button click. And for button click I have another custom class where I am handling all the click events(not in the fragmnet class).Would you be able to give an example based on that...your help is really appreciated.

Comment: @Paramita I update my answer base on `so I need the activity to listen on every button click`, but about request `And for button click I have another custom class where I am handling all the click events(not in the fragmnet class`, I am not clearly, can you explain more ?

Comment: Hi, Gianh..my problem is solved. I tried to make an interface in my custom ButtonClick class and the callback to MainActivity as suggested by you. Thanks to you for your great help..really appreciate. It worked. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using support library, try using `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the theme whether you have used action bar theme with this activity
Also check if you are extending your activity your with AppCompatActivity
then use getSupportActionBar()

Comment: I am already extending my Activity with AppcompatActicity and I am using NoActionBar theme as I am using it with navigationdrawer.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is solved now. What I did is, created an Interface, and gave a callback to my Activity class. Thanks to @GianhTran for suggesting the solution. It is working well.

Here is my code snippet:

My Custom Button class(UtilOnClickListener.java):

//Created an Interface

```
public interface OnActionBarListener {
  void onChangeActionBarTitle(int score);
 }
```

// Initialized it in the constructor of that class

```
public class UtilOnClickListener {

public UtilOnClickListener(View view) {

if (Calculator.getContext() instanceof MainActivity) {
mListener = (OnActionBarListener) Calculator.getContext();
}
}
}
```

And here is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UtilOnClickListener.OnActionBarListener {

 @Override  
public void onChangeActionBarTitle(int score) {
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Integer.toString(score));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had to explicitly find the toolbar and set
it.  Just set actionbar didn't work.  Also, in my case the toolbar was in google supplied code so finding it was ... interesting and I I had to make sure I had the right toolbar type.  For me, the Kotlin code looked like:

```
  import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  ...
  val toolbar = requireActivity()
      .findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
  toolbar?.title = getString(R.string.search_deck,
            currentDeck.deckName)
```